# explorer.exe crashes whenever I select anything

Tags: windows-7, windows, windows-explorer, crash

Whenever I select a file or multiple files, explorer.exe immediately crashes.
The problem has spread, and now effects clicking on Advanced System Settings in the System panel (<kbd>Win</kbd>+<kbd>PauseBreak</kbd>, in the sidebar).

I already tried enabling Data Execution Prevention as recommended by most threads on explorer.exe freezes, and that fixed it for a little while. But it came back and won't go away.

One of the crash reports:

```
Fault bucket 50989770, type 4 
Event Name: APPCRASH 
Response: Not available 
Cab Id: 0

Problem signature: 
P1: explorer.exe 
P2: 6.1.7601.17567 
P3: 4d672ee4
P4: MSVCR100.dll 
P5: 10.0.40219.325 
P6: 4df2bcac 
P7: c0000005 
P8: 000000000003c145 
P9:  
P10: 

Attached files: C:\Users\Owner\AppData\Local\Temp\WERBECD.tmp.WERInternalMetadata.xml

These files may be available here: [crash file location]

Analysis symbol:
Rechecking for solution: 0 
Report Id: [a report id]
Report Status: 1
```

How can I identify what causes this?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Synergy's Explorer extension is the problem (or, it was for me). Using a program like [ShellExView](http://www.nirsoft.net/utils/shexview.html) find the Synergy extension (`C:\Program Files\Synergy\synwinxt.dll` by default) and disable it. Or, if your problem prevents even getting into normal Windows, you can rename the file to a different name in Safe Mode and restart.

[Source](http://answers.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/forum/windows_7-windows_programs/windows-explorer-crashes-on-startup-and-cant-be/4a50f7a0-8abf-45f7-9cfd-610b91957da2), thank you auggy.